# How do I grab a comments class after a successful ajax form submit then display it with out page refresh?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to get ".comment_container" for the post just made and place it after the last comment.

Each comment and it's related content is stored in a ".comment_container" class.

The code below does what I need but not 100%. Rather than append the word TEST I want to append the new comment_contaner holding the comment just posted.

I've been cracking at this all day and this is how far I've come. I would appreciate some solutions with examples if possible.

**JQuery:**

```
$('#new_comment').on('ajax:success', function(){
  $(this).parent('.post_content').find('.comment_container:last').after("TEST");
});

<% sleep 1 %>
```

**HTML:**

```
       <div class="postHolder">
        <nav class="micropostOptions">
         <ul class="postMenu">
           <li class="deletePost"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Delete post"), m, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :title => m.content, :class => "message_delete" %>
           </li>
           <li class="disableCommenting"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Pause commenting"), "2" %></li>
           <li class="blockCommenter"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Block commenter"), "3" %></li>
           <li class="openInNewWindow"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Open in new window"), "4" %></li>
           <li class="reportAbuse"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Report abuse"), "5" %></li>
         </ul>  
       </nav>


                <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_current_user, :class => "poster_photo"), current_users_username %>







<div class="post_content">
    <div class="post_container">

                        <div class="userNameFontStyle"><%= link_to current_users_username.capitalize, current_users_username %> -
                        <div class="post_time"> <%= time_ago_in_words(m.created_at) %> ago.</div> </div>  
                  <%=  simple_format h(m.content) %> </div>

                        <% if m.comments.any? %>
                   <% comments(m.id).each do |comment| %>

                    <div class="comment_container">
                        <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_commenter(comment), :class => "commenter_photo"), commenter(comment.user_id).username %>

                        <div class="commenter_content"> <div class="userNameFontStyle"><%= link_to commenter(comment.user_id).username.capitalize, commenter(comment.user_id).username %> - <%=  simple_format h(comment.content) %> </div>
                    </div><div class="comment_post_time"> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago. </div>


                   </div>


                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>


                <% if logged_in? %>
                <%= form_for @comment, :remote => true, :html => {:class => "new_comment} do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :micropost_id, :value => m.id %>
                <%= f.text_area :content, :placeholder => 'Post a comment...', :class => "comment_box", :rows => 0, :columns => 0 %>

        <div class="commentButtons">         
          <%= f.submit 'Post it', :class => "commentButton" %>
           <div class="cancelButton"> Cancel </div>
        </div>   
                <% end %>

                <% end %>
    </div>


</div>
```

**Comments controller:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create

         @comment = Micropost.find(params[:comment][:micropost_id]).comments.build(params[:comment])
           respond_to do |format|
                 if @comment.save


                    unless params[:comment][:recipient].blank? # this will be blank when current user is commenting/replying on their own wall
                    recipient = User.find(params[:comment][:recipient])
                    UserMailer.new_wall_post_comment_notification(recipient, current_user).deliver if recipient.email_notification == 1 
                    end
                    format.js   { render :post_comment }
                    else
                    format.js   { render :form_errors }
                    end
           end
    end

end
```

**Comment partial:**

```
<div class="comment_container">

        <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_commenter(@comment), :class => "commenter_photo"), commenter(@comment.user_id).username %>
     <div class="commenter_content"> 

        <div class="userNameFontStyle"><%= link_to commenter(@comment.user_id).username.capitalize, commenter(@comment.user_id).username %> - <%=  simple_format h(@comment.content) %> 
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="comment_post_time"> 
        <%= time_ago_in_words(@comment.created_at) %> ago. 
    </div>

</div>
```

Seems to be working apart from 1 minor issue. Let's say I post 4 comment... 1 after each other. First comment 1, second 2, third 3 and fourth 4.. e.g. 1, 2, 3 and 4 the result I get is this:

[image: Posting 1, 2 , 3 4]

I have a feeling it's something to do with some kind of reset needing to be done after each comment is left. After refreshing the comments display as expected. 1, 2, 3 and 4. Any thoughts?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the partial for rendering your `Comment`s (I guess it should be the `/views/comments/_comment.html.erb`).

Then just replace:

```
.after("TEST");
```

with:

```
.after("<%= j render @comment %>");
```

Comment: Tried that first and my variables wouldn't pass through.

Comment: Right now I'm seeing if I can pass some instance variables to the partial from my comments_controllers create method.

Comment: Of course you can! There is no way that `create` action doesn't know about current `Comment`. Just assign it to the `@comment` variable and your `create.js.erb`(I guess this is where you placed the methioned javascript) will be able to access it. Also it will be avialable inside the parial.

Comment: Hi this is working but there is one minor issue. Please see edited info on my question.

Answer (score 0):

This along with the advice from jdoe fixed my issue

```
$('.new_comment').off().on('ajax:success', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.post_content').find('.comment_container:last').after("<%= j render 'comments/partials/comment' %>");
    $('#comment_content').removeClass("comment_box_focused").addClass("comment_box");
    $(".commentButtons").removeClass("displayButtons");
    $('#comment_content').val("");
    <% sleep 1 %>

});
```

Comment: It's like a 1 second count after the submit button is pressed

Comment: But why?  I don't understand why you would want to intentionally add latency to your app.

Comment: I may add a spinner gif. Sometimes the comment can post so fast the user doesn't realise the comment has been posted.. especially if it's a very short one. Having a spinner or the text change on the submit button to something like "posting" makes them aware of the fact something is happening.

Comment: I think it doesn't effect the speed that the comment is posted just the speed the update is shown back to the user.

Comment: This is probably one of the worst ways of handling that to be honest.  Instead, I would recommend having the comment [fade in](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) when it is added, where the user can visually see that their comment has been added.

Comment: Better. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Even sliding down would be good too. I tried to implement fade in just now and it fadesin the div before the last.

Comment: All sorted now. Thanks for this.